# perl - extracting function arguments from multi line function definitions

Tags: regex, perl

```
eErrorT ChainCtrlInitChains(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl,
    char* name,
    int instance)
{
    ....
}
eErrorT ChainCtrlInit(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, void* pOwner)
{
    ....
}
```

MY CODE

```
open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;
my @arr = <$FILE>;
foreach(@arr){  
   if ($_ =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {
      my $arg = $1;
      my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
      print my @temp = map "$_\n", @arr
            unless $_ =~ /;\s*$/;
     }
}
```

Basically I am extracting function arguments from the function definitions.

But in this case I am only able to extract arguments for 2nd function(ChainCtrlInit) and not for 1st function(ChainCtrlinitchains).

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
pChainCtrl
name
instance

pChainCtrl
pOwner
```

OUTPUT I AM GETTING

```
pChainCtrl
pOwner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the file line by line and so the regex can never extend across multiple lines - if you load the file then make it a single string with embedded new lines it will work

eg a quick hack gives

```
open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;
my @arr = <$FILE>;
my $file = join('',@arr);

 my @matches = $file =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg;
 foreach (@matches) {
      my $arg = $_;
      my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
      print my @temp = map "$_\n", @arr
            unless $_ =~ /;\s*$/;
      print "\n";
  }
```

Comment: thanks.. works fine now. I am new to Perl . thought it will check starting from "(" till it sees ")" even if its in separate lines.

Comment: Save a lot of work with `my $file = do { local $/; <FILE> }` instead of breaking it into lines just to join them again.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is when you do "foreach", $_ in the block inherits each element in the array.
For example,

foreach(@arr).. the first iteration of the loop assign $_ with "eErrorT ChainCtrlInitChains(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl,\n", so your regex will fail.

And you also use temp variables that don't have too much use. I have improved the code as the following:

```
my $arr = do { local $/; <$FILE> }; #Copy one of the comments above.

#note there's a slight difference in the 'while' regex to your code
while ($arr =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* (\( .+? \)) /xsmg) { 
    my @args = $1 =~ /(\w+)[,)]/g; #This assumes what you want always ends in 
    #a ',' or a ')', hence the gentle modification in the 'while' regex.
    local $" = "\n";
    say "@args";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ad-vic, in addition to @atleypnorth's solution to slurp the whole file into a string, there could be a problem within your split-map statement.

this
`my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;`
should be this
`my @arr = map /(\w+)\W*$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;`
because the last element from split gets residual characters.

Once you get the hang of Perl, you could streamline it into this -

```
 $/ = "";
 open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;
 my $str = <$FILE>;

 foreach ( $str =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg ) {
     print map "$_\n", /(\w+) [^\w,]* (?:,|$)/xg ;
     print "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Just a note that this is not recommended for to parse c/c++.